# Can 'if, then and else' keywords be applied within properties of an object or is it strictly kept outside?

Tags: jsonschema

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html
All the examples mentioned in the URL have the 'if, then and else' conditions outside an object's properties. I was just curious to know whether can it be set within properties and still follow the standards?

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country": {
      "enum": ["United States of America", "Canada"]
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": { "country": { "const": "United States of America" } }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?" } }
  },
  "else": {
    "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]" } }
  }
}
```

Could it be done this way?

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country": {
      "enum": ["United States of America", "Canada"]
    },
    "if": {
      "properties": { "country": { "const": "United States of America" } }
    },
    "then": {
      "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?" } }
    },
    "else": {
     "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]" } }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried a JSON-schema lint online and it didn't raise any error however I am unaware of its implementation hence not very sure whether the syntax matches the proposed draft-7 or not.

Motivation to do this within an object's properties is: 
Especially in a large schema file, it feels better if I could define an attribute whose value is conditionally dependent on some other properties right there next to it. Rather than first finishing all the properties then applying conditions separately outside the properties.

Very new to programming - pardon me if this is a very incorrect question.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All keywords, including `if`/`then`/`else` can appear in anything that is a *schema*. The value of the `properties` keyword is defined as an *object* whose values are schemas. Therefore, keywords can not be used as a child of `properties`, but can be used in one of it's values.

If you do something like this ...

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": { "type": "string" },
    "country": { "enum": ["United States of America", "Canada"] },
    "if": {
      "properties": { "country": { "const": "United States of America" } }
    },
    "then": {
      "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?" } }
    },
    "else": {
     "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]" } }
    }
  }
}
```

it is describing an object like ...

```
{
  "street_address": "123 Fake St",
  "country": "United States of America",
  "if": { "country": "United States of America" },
  "then": { "postal_code": "90000" },
  "else": { "postal_code": "A0A 0A0" }
}
```

Notice that "if", "then", "else" are understood as property names, not keywords. Again, this is because the value of `properties` is not a schema, it is an object whose values are schemas. That schema happens to be a valid schema, it just doesn't do what you expect it will do.

You could therefore do something like this ...

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": { "type": "string" },
    "country": { "enum": ["United States of America", "Canada"] },
    "postal_code": {
      "if": { ... },
      "then": { ... },
      "else": { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, it recognizes `if`/`then`/`else` as keywords, but there is no way to write this condition to do what you are trying to do. You have to put it at the top level as the examples you've seen have done.